# RNG randomization strength for PRF seed

Tags: encryption, randomness

Consider a use case that requires the creation of multiple asymmetric key pairs. There are two options for generating random seeds for a PRF:

- Use a software based RNG and generate a new seed for each key pair
- Use a hardware based TRNG, generate a single seed, and increment that value for each new key pair

Would either of these options be superior to the other, in terms of security strengths/weaknesses?

**EDIT**

My thinking is that neither solution above would be necessarily insecure.

The RNG solution would generate less entropy than the TRNG initially, but that may not be a problem, depending on the use case, if no other weaknesses were present.

For the TRNG solution, my understanding is that the larger goal is for the salt value to be unique, rather than secret (the private key needs to be secret). As the seed increments, the PRF will mask any resemblance to the original seed.

Comment: This looks like an assignment to me, because one of these options would never be taken by a serious cryptographer. Please include your own thoughts and mind that we only provide hints for homework style questions.

Comment: Updated question with my thinking. This is not a homework assignment, but I'm definitely not a 'serious cryptographer'. Would appreciate any correction to my understanding.

Comment: So are you going to use the "seed" to seed another RNG or do you plan to use the generated seed directly within the key pair generation?

Comment: I was thinking seed directly to PRF (HMAC, lets say) for KDF. So RNG used once per key pair for the first option, and incremented once per key pair for the second option.

Comment: Asymmetric key pair generation generally takes a PRNG, not a PRF. That's why I was asking.

Comment: Understood, then yes, the value would be used to seed a PRNG. The random value in both cases would NOT be used directly for key pair generation.

Comment: In the first option you don't specify a TRNG at all, so it seems an entropy source is missing. Generally you'd have a TRNG to seed one or more PRNG's. What's wrong with that and why does it seem missing in the options? In option 2 you have a two way connection between the seeds of the software based PRNG, that's generally not a good idea.